# Timestamp to output on html page in Node Red

Tags: node-red

Beginner in Node Red. Looking for some examples using

`inject/timestamp node` and `http in node` to output to html via `http response`.

I'm able to get timestamp output in the `debug node` but the `http response` node returns

> "No Response Object"

**Flow code**

```
[
    {
        "id": "9f006bd1.640c3",
        "type": "http response",
        "z": "d5fed3fc.0eb49",
        "name": "",
        "x": 897.2000122070312,
        "y": 167.1999969482422,
        "wires": [ ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e3c543a2.edb15",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "d5fed3fc.0eb49",
        "name": "setHTTPheader",
        "func": "// If sending JSON data the content type is:\n//msg.headers={\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"}\n\n// For HTML use the content type line below:\nmsg.headers={\"Content-Type\":\"text/html\"}\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "x": 530.2000122070312,
        "y": 178.1999969482422,
        "wires": [ [ "9f006bd1.640c3", "148ad3e4.c6b5bc" ] ]
    },
    {
        "id": "30bfd46d.90b3fc",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "d5fed3fc.0eb49",
        "name": "",
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "date",
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": true,
        "x": 214.1999969482422,
        "y": 118.19999694824219,
        "wires": [ [ "e3c543a2.edb15" ] ]
    },
    {
        "id": "974e0c4.06af17",
        "type": "http in",
        "z": "d5fed3fc.0eb49",
        "name": "/time",
        "url": "/time",
        "method": "get",
        "swaggerDoc": "",
        "x": 199.5,
        "y": 175.40000915527344,
        "wires": [ [ "e3c543a2.edb15" ] ]
    },
    {
        "id": "148ad3e4.c6b5bc",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "d5fed3fc.0eb49",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "console": "false",
        "complete": "payload",
        "x": 895.5000457763672,
        "y": 211.8000030517578,
        "wires": [ ]
    }
]
```

**Flow graph**
[image: Flow]

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not 100% sure if I understand your question but if you are wondering why you get

> "No Response Object"

when firing the upper left `inject node` then the simple answer is because there is no `http response` object to write your output to - it only exists if you trigger your flow via the lower left `http in` node. In your example you could trigger it by opening http://localhost:1880/time in your browser (assumed you are running with the default port).

In case you always want to see the current timestamp in your response just add something like the following to your `function node`:

```
msg.payload = 'Timestamp: ' + Date.now();
```